# want to make swap file from my ubuntu live (on flash drive) to my main hard disk

Tags: command-line, usb-drive, swap

Can any one tell me why the following order gave me unexpected number of arguments?

```
>>>>> fallocate -l 6g /media/309AFD059AFCC87C/ubuntu live drive program files/6g.swap
```

Comment: If you are following a recipe or other post it might be helpful to us if you could include a link to it in your question.

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't look right.

You could try:

```
fallocate -l 6g /media/309AFD059AFCC87C/ubuntu\ live\ drive\ program\ files\/6g.swap
```

or

```
fallocate -l 6g "/media/309AFD059AFCC87C/ubuntu live drive program files/6g.swap"
```